# Custom my MVC route for specific name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have this route:

http://example.com/home/solucoes

But I Would to call like  http://example.com/any-category/any-thing

My controlller is "Home" and action is "solucoes"

I try use it, but not work

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultSolucoes",
            url: "{categoria}/{page}",
            defaults: new { 
                controller = "Home", 
                action = "solucoes", 
                categoria = UrlParameter.Optional,
                page = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: How do you try to use it?

Comment: I want to use the same route/action, but with different urls for use in SEO Optimization.

Comment: is this the first route ?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have that route below the default route. The problem there is that both of these routes are basically identical. So, when the default route catches, it simply looks for a controller named "any-category" and an action named "any-thing". Simply having different parameter names doesn't differentiate one route from another.

You can move your route *above* the default route, as routes are processed top down and the first match wins. However, you've then basically made *this route* the default route, as it will catch all your standard controller/action style URLs. You might consider adding a prefix to the route, for example:

```
url: "categoria/{categoria}/{page}",
```

So then your URLs would be in the form of `/categoria/any-category/any-thing` and you won't have any conflicts.

Comment: Ahh nice! Thats work now Chris. I just put to above the default route and now work perfect! Thanks!